# How can I get a big cross to denote a generalized cartesian product?

Tags: math-mode

I'm trying to get a big cross which I can subscript in order to denote a generalized cartesian product (much like how `\bigcup` works for generalized unions). How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Have you tried to find the symbol on [detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html)? Something like `\bigotimes` without the 'O' maybe?

Comment: @Raphink: Thanks! Yes, I tried both things. ´\bigtimes´ isn't defined, and ´\bigotimes´ produces a cross inscribed inside a circle.

Comment: Isn't the standard(ish) mathematical notation to use `\prod` for n-ary Cartesian products, not a giant `\times`?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Looking in the [The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) reveals a `\bigtimes` symbol defined by the [`mathabx` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/mathabx).

Comment: I just found out (accidentally :)) that the `\bigtimes` symbol is also defined in the [mathtools](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mh) package.

Comment: regarding `mathabx` beware that it changes the shape of many other symbols; it is recommended to extract the code for just the desired symbol(s) into your preamble to avoid unexpected results.

Answer (score 16):

If you don't mind using a different font, `kpfonts` gives you the `\varprod` command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kpfonts}

\begin{document}

$\varprod_{i=1}^n A_i$

\[
  \varprod_{i=1}^n A_i
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

I would be more inclined to use `\prod` to denote a generalised cartesian product, though.

Comment: Strictly speaking, \prod should be the general symbol for product in categorical sense. The Cartesian product is a product in many categories such as sets and modules, but it is not always the case.

Answer (score 6):

I am sure others will come up with simpler solutions, but here is an overkill solution that might be useful:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\Cross}{\mathbin{\tikz [x=1.4ex,y=1.4ex,line width=.2ex] \draw (0,0) -- (1,1) (0,1) -- (1,0);}}%
\begin{document}
$A \Cross B$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Adjust the `x=` and `y=` options to change the size, and the `line width=` to adjust the thickness of the line.  The `\mathbin` ensures that correct spacing for a binary operator is placed around the symbol.

Comment: If you are down voting, it would be helpful it your provided some explanation so others can know what is wrong with this solution, or why you are opposed to this solution.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but you seem to be re-implementing the binary cartesian product symbol, and the OP is asking about a "sigma-style" symbol to apply to the Cartesian product of a family of sets.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang: Ahhh thanks. That clarifies things.

Comment: Still, I wouldn't have downvoted.  I got to this answer from your comments on http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/104164/color-the-faces-of-a-graph and I agree with your POV.

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple command for that in the `mathabx` package:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{mathabx}

\begin{document}
   $\bigtimes\limits_{x=1}$
\end{document}
```

In fact if you find another operator symbol you fancy, you can try the `\limits` command on it. It may actually work. :)

I hope this answers it. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you can use `unicode-math`, the symbol you are looking for is at [U+2A09 'N-ARY TIMES OPERATOR'](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2a09/index.htm)

```
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{equation}
B ⊂ ⨉_{x∈J}A(x)
\end{equation}
```

This package only works on the XeLaTex and LuaLaTeX engines though.

[image: Result of the above code]

Answer (score -4):

Might I suggest a very simple-minded approach?
Why not just use the letter "X"?  Below, I inserted `\sf` to render the symbol more distinguishable

```
$${\sf X}^n_{i=1} A_i = A_1\times \cdots \times A_n$$
```

Comment: Please read the following posts: [Does it matter if I use `\textit` or `\it`, `\bfseries` or `\bf`, etc.](http://goo.gl/ECK5V), [Will two-letter font style commands (`\bf`, `\it`, …) ever be resurrected in LaTeX?](http://goo.gl/u98NT), [Why is `\[` …`\]` preferable to `$$`?](http://goo.gl/GvmWy)