# how can I get the thicker x symbol like the following picture?

Tags: beamer, align, matrices

[image]

I try the `\boldsymbol{\times}`, but it doesn't look right.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).  I would just draw it as in [How can I get a big cross to denote a generalized cartesian product?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/28151/4301) and adjust the `line width` to suit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is bit heavy, but highly customizable.... using `tikz`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}
\newcommand{\mytimes}{ \tikz[baseline=-.55ex] \node [inner sep=0pt,cross out,draw,line width=1pt,minimum size=1ex] (a) {};}
\begin{document}
  \[\begin{bmatrix}
    \times    & \mytimes \\
    \mytimes  & \times
  \end{bmatrix}
  \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is one with `bm`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}
  \[\begin{bmatrix}
    \times    & \bm{\times} \\
    \bm{\times}  & \times
  \end{bmatrix}
  \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The first solution looks very good. Thank you very much.

Comment: The first solution looks very good. Thank you very much.