# How can I define a big plus operator that works like \bigcup?

Tags: math-mode, math-operators, mathtools

I want to define a "`\bigplus`" operator that is a big `+` symbol that changes size according to environment and has limits, just like `\bigcup` works. I've read about defining a "`\bigtimes`" ([How can I get a big cross to denote a generalized cartesian product?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28150/how-can-i-get-a-big-cross-to-denote-a-generalized-cartesian-product)) but the answer doesn't help me since in package [`mathabx`](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/mathabx) there's no "`\bigplus`" command and the package changes many symbols. I found the package [`mathtools`](https://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools), which has the command `\bigtimes`, but also no "`\bigplus`". I found in its source code the command

```
\def\MH_bigtimes_scaler:N #1{%
  \vcenter{\hbox{#1$\m@th\mkern-2mu\times\mkern-2mu$}}}
\def\MH_bigtimes_inner: {
  \mathchoice{\MH_bigtimes_scaler:N \huge}         % display style
             {\MH_bigtimes_scaler:N \LARGE}        % text style
             {\MH_bigtimes_scaler:N {}}            % script style
             {\MH_bigtimes_scaler:N \footnotesize} % script script style
}
\def\MH_csym_bigtimes: {\mathop{\MH_bigtimes_inner:}\displaylimits}
\AtBeginDocument{
  \providecommand\bigtimes{\MH_csym_bigtimes:}
}
```

and tried to copy it, changing `\times` for `+` or `plus` when necessary, and then pasted it in my preamble, but it does not work. If I copy it under the code itself it works, but I don't want to change the code, obviously. I'm looking for a way to define operator commands in general from symbols I already have, like `+`, since that would help me a lot.

Comment: Note, however, that the `mathabx` package does provide a `\bigplus` command.

Comment: You are right, I was mistaken. Actually `mathtools` does not. I've emailed them asking for the command but I believe they didn't get the email.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One can easily make the “big plus” the same size as `\sum`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\bigplus}{%
  \DOTSB\mathop{\mathpalette\mattos@bigplus\relax}\slimits@
}
\newcommand\mattos@bigplus[2]{%
  \vcenter{\hbox{%
    \sbox\z@{$#1\sum$}%
    \resizebox{!}{0.9\dimexpr\ht\z@+\dp\z@}{\raisebox{\depth}{$\m@th#1+$}}%
  }}%
  \vphantom{\sum}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{center}% test bounding box
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\fbox{$\displaystyle\sum$} \fbox{$\displaystyle\bigplus$}
\end{center}

\[
\sum_{i=1}^m\bigplus_{j=1}^n\dots\bigplus_{k=1}^p x_{ijk}
\]
\begin{center}% to test text style
$\sum_{i=1}^m\bigplus_{j=1}^n\dots\bigplus_{k=1}^p x_{ijk}$
\end{center}

\LARGE % test for sizes
\[
\sum_{i=1}^m\bigplus_{j=1}^n\dots\bigplus_{k=1}^p x_{ijk}
\]
\begin{center}% to test text style
$\sum_{i=1}^m\bigplus_{j=1}^n\dots\bigplus_{k=1}^p x_{ijk}$
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, that's a good answer, thank you. What are the differences between this and @Steven B. Segletes 's answer, apart from avoiding using `scalerel` package? Is this how the package does it? I tried both and dots, limits and rescaling seem to work fine.

Comment: One of a great suggestion egreg, you always a master...

Comment: @PedroG.Mattos There is a single command, not two.

Comment: @egreg To clarify, I do not require two commands.  Rather, I provided 2 options to the OP, and he can choose which one of the two he prefers.

Comment: @MadyYuvi Because egreg uses lower level commands to achieve the result, his is no doubt more efficient, whereas mine goes through the `scalerel` package.  If there is an advantage to mine, it is easier to type the definition (and maybe, for a novice, easier to adapt the definition to suit similar needs).  In both cases, we support the smaller (`script` and `scriptscript`) math styles.  In both cases, we scale a box containing a `+` to the proper size.  In both cases, we handle limits and surrounding space in accordance with the requirements of a `\mathop`.

Comment: @PedroG.Mattos Sorry I directed my above comment at the wrong user.

Answer (score 13):

A rip-off of my answer at [How are big operators defined?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116506/how-are-big-operators-defined).  Two completely separate macros are provided (`\foo` and `\barr`), depending on whether one wishes the `\displaystyle` version to grow bigger or stay the same size as `\textstyle`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\foo}{\scalerel*{+}{\sum}}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\barr}{\scalerel*{+}{\textstyle\sum}}
\usepackage{scalerel}

\begin{document}
\[
\foo_{i=3}^{6}(f^2(i))
\]

This is inline: \(\foo_{i=3}^{6}(f^2(i)) \)

\[
\barr_{i=3}^{6}(f^2(i))
\]

This is inline: \(\barr_{i=3}^{6}(f^2(i)) \)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You cannot copy LaTeX3 code into your preamble without taking appropriate preliminary actions.  I’m showing below how the same idea could be implemented through LaTeX2e code.  This solution also supports standard `amsmath` behavior with respect to dots and the [`no`]`sumlimits` option:

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter

\newcommand*\@bigplus[1]{\vcenter{\hbox{#1$\m@th +$}}}
\newcommand*\bigplus{%
    \DOTSB % omit this line if you are not using the amsmath package
    \mathop{%
        \mathchoice
            {\@bigplus \huge}%
            {\@bigplus \LARGE}%
            {\@bigplus {}}%
            {\@bigplus \footnotesize}%
    }%
    \slimits@ % omit this line if you are not using the amsmath package
}

\makeatother



\begin{document}

In-line: \( \bigplus_{i=3}^{6} f^2(i) \).
Displayed: \[ \bigplus_{i=3}^{6} f^2(i) \]
Behavior with dots:
\[
    \bigplus_{i_{1}=0}^{n_{1}}\dots\bigplus_{i_{k}=0}^{n_{k}}
        f(i_{1},\dots,i_{k})
\]

\end{document}
```

This is the output:

[image: Output of the code]

---

## Addition

As @egreg has pointed out in [his comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/394901/how-can-i-define-a-big-plus-operator-that-works-like-bigcup#comment981981_394912), the above answer—which, however, merely mimics what the `mathtools` package does for `\bigtimes`—is buggy.  The correct solution is to use the `mathabx` package, which, contrary to what is stated in the question, does provide the `\bigplus` “large operator”.  This solution uses characters drawn from fonts specifically designed for the purpose and, hence, does not depend on the extensions provided by the `graphics`/`graphicx` package; in particular, it works also with DVI output (for what this is worth).

If you don’t like the changes that the `mathabx` package applies to mathematical symbols in general, you can always load the appropriate fonts yourself and define only the commands you are interested in.
The following example defines `\bigplus` as well as `\bigtimes`.  Allow me a few remarks:

- the code supports the features of the `amsmath` package concerning
  dots and “limits”, if that package is loaded;
- contrary to what the `mathabx` package itself does, the `mathx`
  font family is defined in such a way to take advantage of the
  smaller font sizes installed in today’s distributions.

The latter contrivance permits to improve the output at sizes smaller than 10 points, making it look better than it does in solutions that use `graphics` scaling.

Here is the code:

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\usepackage{amsmath} % comment out to see changes

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathx}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathx}{m}{n}{
    <5> <6> <7> <8> <9> <10> gen * mathx
    <10.95> mathx10
    <12> <14.4> <17.28> <20.74> <24.88> mathx12
}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathx}{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\bigplus} {\mathop}{mathx}{"90}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\bigtimes}{\mathop}{mathx}{"91}

\makeatletter

\@ifpackageloaded{amsmath}{%
    \@ifundefined{coprod@}{}{
        \typeout{*** Applying amsmath patches to \protect\bigplus\space
                    and \protect\bigtimes. ***}
        \global\let\bigplus@\bigplus
        \gdef\bigplus{\DOTSB\bigplus@\slimits@}
        \global\let\bigtimes@\bigtimes
        \gdef\bigtimes{\DOTSB\bigtimes@\slimits@}
    }
}{}

\makeatother



\begin{document}

In-line: \( \bigplus_{i=3}^{6} f^2(i) \).
Displayed: \[ \bigplus_{i=3}^{6} f^2(i) \]
Behavior with dots:
\[
    \bigplus_{i_{1}=0}^{n_{1}}\dots\bigplus_{i_{k}=0}^{n_{k}}
        f(i_{1},\dots,i_{k})
\]

In-line: \( \bigtimes_{i=3}^{6} f^2(i) \).
Displayed: \[ \bigtimes_{i=3}^{6} f^2(i) \]
Behavior with dots:
\[
    \bigtimes_{i_{1}=0}^{n_{1}}\dots\bigtimes_{i_{k}=0}^{n_{k}}
        f(i_{1},\dots,i_{k})
\]

Now it works in footnotes too.\footnote{As this example shows.
In-line: \( \bigplus_{i=0}^{n} f(i) \), \( \bigtimes_{i=0}^{n} f(i) \).
Displayed: \[ \bigplus_{i=0}^{n} f(i) \ne \bigtimes_{i=0}^{n} f(i) \]
That's good!}

\LARGE
\verb|\LARGE| text.
In-line: \( \bigtimes_{i=3}^{6} f^2(i) \).
Displayed: \[ \bigtimes_{i=3}^{6} f^2(i) \]
Behavior with dots:
\[
    \bigtimes_{i_{1}=0}^{n_{1}}\dots\bigtimes_{i_{k}=0}^{n_{k}}
        f(i_{1},\dots,i_{k})
\]

\end{document}
```

And here is the output it yields:

[image: Output of the second code sample]

Comment: This won't scale properly at different sizes.

Comment: Of course, @egreg’s remark applies to `mathtools`’s `\bigtimes` as well.  Indeed, I would regard this as a bug.