# Define a new big operator in ConTeXt

Tags: context, math-operators

I would like to replace the `sum` symbol by a big plus as Pedro G. Mattos wanted to do here [How can I define a big plus operator that works like \bigcup?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/394901/how-can-i-define-a-big-plus-operator-that-works-like-bigcup).

In the wiki I found that the command I should use is `\definemathsymbol`. However I am confused about how to adapt the symbol for both inline and display maths.

A solution might exactly be https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Product_integral but I do not get it and I do not want to use various commands such as `prodi`, `PRODI`... but only the `sum` one. Is it possible?

The code is very basic.

```
\starttext
    Solve for \m{n} the following:
    \startformula
        \sum_{k=0}^n k = 6
    \stopformula
    {\bf Hint:} \m{\sum_{k=0}^2 k = 3}
\stoptext
```

[image: Output]

If you solve the problem, an answer to replace `prod` by a big `times` would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The is no such things as a “big plus“ in Unicode.  However, there is a big times as per your second request.

```
\starttext
    Solve for \m{n} the following:
    \startformula
        \bigtimes_{k=0}^n k = 6
    \stopformula
    \bold{Hint:} \m{\bigtimes_{k=0}^2 k = 3}
\stoptext
```

[image]

---

You can make your own big plus by just scaling the regular plus symbol.  This is typographically not very consistent because it also scales the line width.

```
\define\bigplus{%
  \mathop{%
    \mathchoice
      {\dobigplus{2000}}%
      {\dobigplus{1500}}%
      {\dobigplus{ 900}}%
      {\dobigplus{ 700}}%
  }%
}

\define[1]\dobigplus{%
  \vcenter{\hbox{\scale[scale=#1]{$+$}}}%
}

\starttext
    Solve for \m{n} the following:
    \startformula
        \bigplus_{k=0}^n k = 6
    \stopformula
    \bold{Hint:} \m{\bigplus_{k=0}^2 k = 3}
\stoptext
```

[image]