# Putting a union symbol inside union

Tags: math-mode, symbols, math-operators

I would like to have a custom union symbol `\ccup` that is essentially two unions placed one inside another. A rotated `\Subset` works just fine for a "small" union, as shown in the image below; however, I need to have a similar symbol `\bigccup` for a "big" union just like `\bigcup`.

Rescaling `\Subset` does not look good at all for big unions. How could I make the symbol I need from scratch? Ideally, it should have the same dimensions as the original `\bigcup`.

[image]

Comment: I would be inclined to compose it from a `\big up` and a `\cup`, although the fact that this symbol does not otherwise exist would give me pause.

Comment: Please give a minimal working example and post your `\ccup` code.

Comment: Isn't `\Cup` from the `amssymb`-package what you are looking for, at least for the "small" symbol? I used http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html to search for such a symbol.

Comment: @Οὖτις Ah, yes indeed. I did not realize there was such a symbol already implemented in `amssymb`! However, there doesn't seem to be a "big" version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here an idea similar to [Οὖτις's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/605575/82917) but trying to improve spacing. The trouble is that simply scaling `\Cup` does not work well, because the glyph sticks outside of its bounding box if compared to `\bigcup`:

```
\fboxrule.1pt \fboxsep-\fboxrule
\fbox{$\Cup$} \fbox{$\displaystyle\bigcup$}
```

[image]

For the scaling to work properly (and to obtain decently placed limits) we must first add some vertical padding.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\bigCup}{\mathop{\mathpalette\big@Cup\relax}\slimits@}

\newcommand*{\big@Cup}[2]{%
   \setbox\z@=\hbox{\m@th$#1\Cup$}%
   \setbox\z@=\vtop{\vbox{\kern.2\ht\z@\copy\z@}\kern.1\ht\z@}%
   \setbox\tw@=\hbox{\m@th$#1\bigcup$}%
   \vcenter{\hbox{\resizebox{!}{1.4\ht\tw@}{\box\z@}}}%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

D: $\displaystyle\bigcup_a^b c \qquad \displaystyle\bigCup_a^b c$\par\medskip
T: $\bigcup_a^b c \qquad \bigCup_a^b c$\par\medskip
S: $\scriptstyle\bigcup_a^b c \qquad \bigCup_a^b c$\par\medskip
SS: $\scriptscriptstyle\bigcup_a^b c \qquad \bigCup_a^b c$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Short comments:

- One could try making the new symbol thinner but that starts deforming lines a wee bit too much for my taste.
- The `\slimits@` comes from `amsmath` and is used by all sum-like big operators. It will obey the `sumlimits`/`nosumlimits` package options.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/394904/237192) I propose the following as a starting point.

[image]

You can see that the linewidth of `\bigCup` is too much and it does not perfectly meet `\bigcup`'s height, but right now I don't know how to fix that.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,scalerel}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\bigCup}{\scalerel*{\Cup}{\bigcup}}

\begin{document}
   This is inline: $A\Cup B$
   \begin{equation*}
      \bigCup_{i=1}^\infty A_i% your symbol
      \quad%
      \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i% normal \bigcup
   \end{equation*}
\end{document}
```