# How to get a big "+" symbol (i.e., equivalent to "\bigtimes")?

Tags: mathtools

Consider the commands `$\bigtimes$` provided by (some package loaded by) `mathtools`, which produces a big cross. My question is simple. Is there any way to obtain a big "+" symbol (i.e., of the size of $\bigtimes$)? I know this is completely unseen mathematical notation, but I'm curious to see how one would go about getting one such cross.

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}

% PACKAGES LOADING

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

$\bigtimes$

\end{document}
```

Here the output (in red, mi handwritten desired symbol):

[image]

**How can I get a big "+" symbol?**

Thank you all for your time.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/394901/219947

Comment: Thank you for your comment. As pointed out, the question solved in the post he links. Hence, I'm voting to close the question.