# How to extract code for desired symbols from package into preamble?

Tags: math-mode, fonts

I'm trying to follow the instructions here for getting a big 'X' for an iterated Cartesian product:
[How can I get a big cross to denote a generalized cartesian product?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28150/how-can-i-get-a-big-cross-to-denote-a-generalized-cartesian-product#comment55321_28152). However, I have no idea where to start.

Comment: Simply load `mathtools` in the place of `amsmath` and use `\bigtimes`.