# What is the correspondence symbol with a hat or wedge over equals?

Tags: symbols

I would like to produce a new equal symbol looking like this.
[image].

What is the best way to do that ? Pure TeX ? TiKz ?

I'm looking for ways to do that rather than to a ready to use solution such as to be able to other new symbols alone.

Comment: This looks to me like Unicode U+2259, estimates (`\wedgeq` in the stix fonts).  What is your intended meaning? (If it's the same. I'll try to add an answer, but since I don't have easy access to a tex system at the moment, including a visual will be difficult.)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Before somebody suggests `MnSymbol`…

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\providecommand{\hateq}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\my@hat@eq\relax}}
\newcommand{\my@hat@eq}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1=$}%
  \ooalign{%
    \hidewidth\raisebox{-0.3\ht\z@}{$\m@th#1\widehat{}$}\hidewidth\cr
    \box\z@\cr
  }%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$A\cong B\hateq C$                           

\end{document}
```

[image]

With `\hat` instead of `\widehat`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\providecommand{\hateq}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\my@hat@eq\relax}}
\newcommand{\my@hat@eq}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1=$}%
  \ooalign{%
    \hidewidth\raisebox{-0.2\ht\z@}{$\m@th#1\hat{}$}\hidewidth\cr
    \box\z@\cr
  }%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$A\cong B\hateq C$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @campa Yes, thanks!

Comment: How is this different from U+2259, estimates (`\wedgeq` in the `stix` fonts)?  (I know the shape is slightly different, but what about the meaning?)

Comment: @barbarabeeton It's the same, I guess. No idea what meaning the OP is assigning to the symbol.

Comment: This symbol is used to define methods in the B language used to specify and prove programs.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Is there an equivalent of detextify for unicode characters ?

Comment: @projetmbc -- I don't know of any equivalent of detexify for Unicode, but it might be reasonable to make a suggestion to the detexify developer to add Unicode IDs to the returned information.  It doesn't look like the stix font info has gotten into detexify, so that's also a plausible request.  (The stix font and the addition of many symbols to unicode progressed in tandem.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton maybe http://shapecatcher.com/?

Comment: @Rmano -- Yes, excellent!  Thanks.  But it doesn't give the TeX names, so I still don't know how to find a symbol (easily) in the comprehensive symbols list unless one already knows the name.

Answer (score 12):

What you want could be obtained using

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\circumeq}{\mathrel{\widehat{=}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
a \circumeq b
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Better `\mathrel{\widehat{=}}`

Comment: Thanks but how to do that "all by hand" if I want to do other new symbols using existing symbols and possibly simple polylines.

Comment: @projetmbc: An example of how to make symbols in TixZ is at [How can I get a big cross to denote a generalized cartesian product?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/28151/4301).

Comment: @projetmbc OK. I suggest then having a look at (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22371/subseteq-circ-as-a-single-symbol-open-subset) with a fine course on `\ooalign`

Comment: Thanks for the two links.

Comment: Another possibility is playing with the `\stackinset` command from ` stackengine` (see § 2.3.10 in the documentation).

Answer (score 8):

The ≙ symbol is U+2259 in Unicode.  It has the name `\wedgeq` in several newer packages, including `unicode-math` and `stix`.  It is `\hateq` in two older ones, `mnsymbol` and `fdsymbol`.  One completely obsolete one, `boisik`, has `\corresponds`.

**Edit:** Sorry, just noticed that Barbara Beeton said that in a comment first.  Props!